# Shopware database connection not working from CLI

Tags: symfony, shopware

I have a working Shopware installation running on my server and I am trying to execute some commands from the terminal through ssh. The Shop itself runs perfectly fine, so the database connection is correct. However, when I try to run CLI scripts like `bin/console plugin:list` I get `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`. I feel like the CLI is trying to connect to the DB via socket and not via TCP. However, I am clueless where to look or change the behaviour. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your `DATABASE_URL` in the .env look like? What does `export` print? Maybe for some reason you are overwriting the `DATABASE_URL` in the console. It is also possible that the `.env` is wrong and the webserver supplies a different, correct `DATABASE_URL` in the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set your database host to **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost**?
There is a forum post about the same issue:

https://forum.shopware.com/t/bin-console-an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstate-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/67109

Comment: Oh, I stumbled across this a while ago when researching another issue and totally forgot... Thanks!